# Drawing Rectangle in PictureBox

Tags: vb.net

I am constructing a screenshot program and I need to be able to have the user select a region of the screenshot with their mouse. So far I have been able to program dragging from top-left to bottom-right, but my attempts to do bottom-right to top-left have been unsuccessful. How should this be done?

This is the working code for top-left to bottom-right:

```
If e.X > SelectedPoint.X And e.Y > SelectedPoint.Y Then
            recsize = New Point(e.X - SelectedPoint.X, e.Y - SelectedPoint.Y)
            rectangle = New Rectangle(SelectedPoint, recsize)
```

Here is the full code:

```
If IsMouseDown = True Then
        Screenshot_PicBox.Refresh()
        Dim recsize As Point
        Dim rectangle As Rectangle
        If e.X > SelectedPoint.X And e.Y > SelectedPoint.Y Then
            recsize = New Point(e.X - SelectedPoint.X, e.Y - SelectedPoint.Y)
            rectangle = New Rectangle(SelectedPoint, recsize)
        ElseIf e.X < SelectedPoint.X And e.Y > SelectedPoint.Y Then
            recsize = New Point(e.X - SelectedPoint.X, e.Y - SelectedPoint.Y)
            SelectedPoint = New Point(-SelectedPoint.X, SelectedPoint.Y)
            rectangle = New Rectangle(SelectedPoint, recsize)
        End If
        Screenshot_PicBox.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rectangle)
    End If
```

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is very likely not the way to go.  What you are drawing will not persist.

Comment: What do you mean by "persist"? The way I am planning to have it work is more for the visual feedback and the code will not necessarily use the shape to crop the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. It doesn't use `Dim recsize As Point` however if you prefer, you can substitute it back in:

```
If IsMouseDown = True Then
    Screenshot_PicBox.Refresh()
    Dim rectangle As New Rectangle
            If e.X > SelectedPoint.x Then
                'left to right
                rectangle.Width = e.X - SelectedPoint.x
                rectangle.X = SelectedPoint.x
            Else
                'right to left
                rectangle.Width = SelectedPoint.x - e.X
                rectangle.X = e.X
            End If
            If e.Y > SelectedPoint.Y Then
                'top to bottom
                rectangle.Height = e.Y - SelectedPoint.Y
                rectangle.Y = SelectedPoint.Y
            Else
                'bottom to top
                rectangle.Height = SelectedPoint.Y - e.Y
                rectangle.Y = e.Y
            End If
    Screenshot_PicBox.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rectangle)
End If
```

Comment: I've been reworking this program in C# and when I saw this code I remembered where it came from. It did indeed work, and I can't believe I forgot to thank you & +1! So thank you, and I'm very sorry!